# Creating a Horizontal Sliding Menu at bottom with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment-tab-host

I need to create a horizontal bottom scrolling bar with button .
On click of button it should open new `Fragment` or `Activity`. It should also have `ViewPageSlider` effect on it .

How can I achieve it?

I have tried with `TabHost` for buttons at bottom .But no sliding effect .

Then I have tried with `PagerTabStrip` . But it gives a effect of buttons at sideways or having too much space and at a time only one button fully visible at center .

I basically want a horizontal scrolling tab at bottom of page and on click on each button opens new activity or fragment and the bottom horizontal bar gives me leverage of adding new buttons if in future.